# Set the same font for different input languages in Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, fonts

For example, if I set a default frame font to Terminus:

```
ELISP> (version)
"GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)\n of 2015-04-11 on LEG570"

ELISP> (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Terminus-10"))
((font . "Terminus-10")
 (height . 45)
 (vertical-scroll-bars . left))
```

then open a new frame, switch to `*scratch*` buffer & type something in Ukrainian, Emacs suddenly uses Consolas font for the typed text:

[image: A screenshot of a Emacs *scratch* buffer]

How do I force Emacs to use Terminus font for Cyrillic characters too? (Terminus supports Cyrillic for sure, because I use it in the Cygwin terminal & it works fine there.)

Comment: Have you looked at how to [globally change font](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts)? Or is this a problem with just that particular font?

Comment: Apparently, it's only Terminus. I found no problems with 'Courier New' or 'Liberation Mono'.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `set-fontset-font` to force emacs to use a specified font for a given range of characters.

```lisp
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default"
                  (cons (decode-char 'ucs #x0400)
                        (decode-char 'ucs #x052F))
                  (font-spec :size 10 :name "Terminus"))
```

More information about Font Sets can be found in the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontSets). The range of unicode characters above should correspond to the "Cyrillic" and "Cyrillic Supplements" unicode blocks, as listed in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block).

Comment: Now it displays boxes: [a screenshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pvLvF9MyY88/VgKd1HvJP3I/AAAAAAAAAh8/kAsqz9ID3kc/s1600-Ic42/emacs-in-windows-2.png)

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with Terminus itself. Maybe the font wasn't installed correctly... But in any case, even when forced, Emacs doesn't manage to display Cyrillic characters with Terminus. Which also explains why it wouldn't use it in the first place.